# Standard multiline textbox, would like every line bulleted automatically

Tags: winforms, textbox

I have a multi-line textbox in which I'd like every newline to also include a bullet character and a space before the next line of characters.  Chr(149) AKA hex 95 looks good with the font I'm using.  Further, the first line should have a bullet which appears automatically upon adding any text.

Basically, I want a textbox that's nothing but a list of bulleted items.  I don't want to give the user the ability to italicize or anything else, so no Richtextbox.

I can handle this upon loading data into the textbox with a simple replace, but I'd like it to happen on-the-fly, while typing or while pasting from the clipboard, with bullets added automatically after every [Enter] keystroke or upon pasting text with linebreaks, and without the text cursor jumping around inappropriately.

Since I often see replies with "Why would you do this?" I'll explain: The user will use this textbox to enter a few brief points about a particular customer, such as "Gate code #1234" or "Customer doesn't like garlic." or "Make sure to mention her dog." It could be almost anything, and occasionally it's a few sentences, but each "point" (even if it's a paragraph) should stand out as visually distinct.  I don't want a blank line eating up screenspace to separate paragraphs, but bullets will make each "entry" distinctively obvious as its own point.  This is especially valuable when a given point ends near the right side of the textbox, so the next point doesn't appear to be part of the preceding point.

My code below "kinda starts to work" and it could be improved by placing the text cursor back where it was while typing (using Selstart) instead of jumping to the beginning, but I haven't gotten that far because it also creates issues when deleting the bullet, and when pasting or cutting.  It could also be improved by adding a bullet before the first line. Those things are easy.

I'd like a simple "linebreak = linebreak and bullet" algorithm that works on the fly with cutting, pasting, typing, deleting and I suspect it already exists somewhere but I haven't found such code.

Or, if there's a simple way to give the textbox a "custom font" in which the linebreaks actually include a visible glyph that looks like a big dot, that would work too.

Thanks for reading my question.

```
Private Sub tbOfficeNotes_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbOfficeNotes.TextChanged
    Static MakingChanges As Boolean = False
    If MakingChanges Then Exit Sub
    Dim s As String = Replace(Replace(tbOfficeNotes.Text, vbCrLf, vbLf), vbCr, vbLf)
    'The line above replaces any form of newline with LF only.
    s = Replace(s, Chr(149) & " ", "")
    MakingChanges = True
    'Avoids a recursive loop as the next line would force this event to trigger from itself.
    tbOfficeNotes.Text = Replace(s, vbLf, vbCrLf & Chr(149) & " ")
    MakingChanges = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I removed "Visual Studio" since the IDE shouldn't be the matter here - could you please add the respective tag if you are targetting either WinForms or WPF?

Comment: And if you're actually using VB, please use that tag rather than C#. (Or don't use a language tag at all.)

Comment: Changed the tags.  Thanks both of you.

Comment: Use a RichTextBox: bullets and indentation are already part of the implementation. *I don't want to give the user the ability to italicize or anything else*. Not relevant or related to the desired results.

Comment: Absolutely it's relevant.  How is it not relevant?